# Maintaining Sub-Menus in NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I  am sorting NSPopUpButton using the following bindings:

```
[arrayController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"displayElements" options:nil];
[popUpButton bind:@"content" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:nil];
[popUpButton bind:@"contentValues" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.title" options:nil];
```

Where **displayElements** is a NSMutable array of NSMenuItem

```
displayElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"one" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""],
                                                              [[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"two" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""],
                                                              [[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"three" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""],
                                                              nil];
```

and the sorting is working just fine.

Now the issue is that if I add a Sub-Menu to any of the menu Items and after that I add a new NSMenuItem to the array controller, the Sub-Menu Previously added disappears as shown in images below:

Before adding New Item:

[image]

After adding a new Item:

[image]

I am adding a new NSMenuItem using the statement:

```
[arrayController addObject:[[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:[newItemTextField stringValue] action:nil keyEquivalent:@""]];
```

The Same behavior is being displayed when we sort the elements.
Any ideas on fixing this problem??

Comment: @Jacob Here is the code I am using to add the sub-menu          `[[popUpButton menu] setSubmenu:defaultSubMenu forItem:[popUpButton itemAtIndex:[indexValue intValue]]]`                                                                                                                                     where **popUpButton** is an outlet of _NSPopUpButton_ and **indexValue** is an outlet of _NSTextField_ from which user enters the index at which he/she wants to add the sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if instead of adding it `forItem:[popUpButton itemAtIndex:[indexValue intValue]]` you'll add it to the item in the arrayController instead?

I suspect that when you later add a menu item in ArrayController, the binding causes NSPopUpMenu itself to create new NSMenuItems from the values in the NSArrayController. And these items in array controller don't have the submenus, since you created it directly in the PopUp button.

Just as you add the new items in Array Controller, I suppose you should add submenus to the items in the Array Controller.

If when you add the submenu to the item in array controller you don't see the submenu appear in the button itself, it probably means that you need to trigger the binding again so that the PopUp button will rebuild its menu. You can do this by wrapping the code that adds the submenu to array controller with:
`[arrayController willChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];` and 
`[arrayController didChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];`

Comment: `[arrayController willChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];             
    [[[arrayController arrangedObjects]objectAtIndex:[indexValue intValue]]setSubmenu:defaultSubMenu];                             
    [arrayController didChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];`           Is this what you mean by wrapping, or am I just misunderstanding @Jacob

Comment: Its not working. However, the sub-menu is being added ( _I printed arrayController using NSLog  and I can see a sub-menu added on the console_ ). But the sub-menu is not yet being displayed in popup button. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you take a similar approach with self. displayElements? Update the submenu to displayElements item and wrap it in [self will/didChangeValueForKey:@"displayElements"]